# Basic Javascript Concatenation Question

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I need some help with concatenating in Javascript.

I've got an array. The value of:

```
(args['type'])
```

is `TERRAIN`.

In another array, I've got:

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: parseInt( args['zoom'] ),
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: 
  };
```

I want to set `mapTypeId` to `google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN` (using whatever value is held in `args['type']` instead of hardcoding `TERRAIN` ).

How do I concatenate it in this situation?

Comment: You're not trying to concatenate anything, you're just trying to access a property dynamically. By the way, `args['zoom']` is discouraged. You should always use `args.zoom` if you know at the time of writing what the name of the property is. Makes your code clearer

Comment: @Juan Mendes, Thank you for your solution. You're right. It's not concatenation. I didn't know what to call it. I learned something new. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
google.maps.MapTypeId[args.type];
```

To dynamically call object properties you can use this syntax.

`args.type` and `args['type']` are functionally identical.